# Capacitive Switch for a Silent XLR Dynamic Microphone Push-To-Talk Button

Tags: switches, microphone, xlr

I have a few of these TTP223 Capacitive Switch modules.

I see tutorials for making a momentary switch out of it by powering it with 5vdc to turn an LED on and off.

I also see allot of tutorials for making a power switch for a 120v AC lightbulb using transistors, resistors, relays, etc.

I just want to use it for a very simple operation, to use it as a momentary spst switch to interrupt one lead of a an XLR jack to make a push-to-talk microphone circuit.

There is no power to the dynamic microphone (no phantom or anything). It's a plain dynamic "passive" Shure SM58.

I use a mechanical momentary spst as a "push-to-talk" by interrupting one of the leads in a straight XLR to XLR connection.

Is there a way to "drop in" a TTP223 module in place of the mechanical spst momentary switch?

As the TTP223 module uses power, having the LED would be a nice thing to show that the button is pushed, but that is not necessary. I mainly just want the silent push-to-talk button.

[image]

Comment: jimj31 - Hi, You posted an "answer". However it was asking a clarification question and an *answer* should not be used for asking a question. Therefore I have converted your post into a comment (since that is how [clarification questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) should be asked). || Since you asked the question, please **don't** use the box labeled "Your Answer" below unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer).

Comment: As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules here differ from typical forums. Thanks.

Comment: FYI If you want to add image links in a comment, you can use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. The draft answer (or question) is used only to upload the image & is then discarded.

Comment: I am going to add a 5v relay. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Without power, no. The sensor needs power to operate.

If phantom power was available, then you could potentially use the output of the TTP223 to drive some kind of switch, solid state or otherwise. You might want to look at ensuring a soft turn-on, as connecting an audio circuit suddenly can cause undesirable pops.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of having the sensor receive power, but also using it as a switch. But you are saying I would still need a relay in the circuit? I did find this very simple circuit for a talkback switch that shorts two pins. [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3c2H.jpg)

Comment: That sensor just gives out an output, high or low, so you'd have to find some way of using this to control the audio, once you got power to it. That circuit would work for a passive microphone, though if there's phantom power on the circuit it would short the power out.